# how to shuffle list(arrayList> with my own objects?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, shuffle

when i make somethink like this:

```
    List<Player> gamers = JackpotGame.getUnsortedGamerList();
    gamers = Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

but i have error: http://scr.hu/1det/a13hi
im sure that method getUnsortedGamerList return me List

Answer (score 1):

change

```
gamers = Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

to

```
Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

`shuffle` mutates the passed `List` instance and has no return value.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
gamers = Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

to

```
Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

The static `shuffle` method of the **Collections** class has a `void` return type.

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle`  randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness, and has no return.

Try to change this:

```
 gamers = Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```

With:

```
Collections.shuffle(gamers);
```